# Smooth camera rotation unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, rotation, unityscript

I create third person with camera. The camera will move in sync with the mouse move. I create script for camera move, its work but when the speed is high then everything starts to shake.

How force the camera move smooth?

```
Vector3 rotation = new Vector3();
rotation = this.transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
float ver = Input.mousePosition.y - mouse_position.y;
difference_y = difference_y ?? ver;
rotation.y += (float)(((Input.mousePosition.x - mouse_position.x) / one_degree_per_pixel_hor));
rotation.x += (float)((-(Input.mousePosition.y - mouse_position.y) / one_degree_per_pixel_ver));
rotation.z = 0;

if (difference_y != 0) {
    //  Forward tilt
    if (difference_y < 0) {
        if (rotation.x > max_slope_forward && rotation.x < max_slope_back) rotation.x = max_slope_forward;
    }
    //  Back tilt
    else {
        if (rotation.x < max_slope_back && rotation.x > max_slope_forward && rotation.x != max_slope_forward) rotation.x = max_slope_back;
    }
}

difference_y = ver;
this.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(-Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"), Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"), 0),Time.deltaTime*SpeedRotation);
rotation = this.transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
rotation.z = 0;
this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotation);
mouse_position = Input.mousePosition;
```

Comment: have a look at: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html and http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Lerp.html and https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/scripting/linear-interpolation

Comment: Also, please consider to add the language of your code in the tags (like C# or Javascript), it add coloration to your code and make it more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use Linear Interpolation (lerp function) as also suggest JinJi in the comment.

[Here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/scripting/linear-interpolation) is the official tutorial

The Lerp function will change the value `from` to the value `to` smoothly at the interval time.

> `Lerp(float from, float to, float time)`

With your code, you code do something like this

```
// Save the original rotation
OrgRotation = this.transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
rotation = OrgRotation;
// Do your stuff here
this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(OrgRotation, Quaternion.Euler(rotation), 0.5f);
```